# Is using an  Oracle persistent connection needed  with .net to maintain a session?

Tags: .net, oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net

I am writing ASP.NET application with Oracle using ODP.NET to execute any DML, open a new connection and execute a Query which all work fine.
My problem is that I am writing packages and need to save some record something similar to:

```
pkg_name.putdata(param1,param2,......)
pkg_name.save()
```

Using `pkg_name.putdata(param1,param2,......)`,  this method is written in Oracle and I needto initialize package properties and use `pkg_name.save()` to insert data in Oracle database,

When i call `save()` after `putdata()`, I can't locate any data in my  package variables.

Will using  persistent connection fix this?
I also want to use Oracle temporary tables to store session information till the user is logged out.

Please suggest how can i do this task or refer me to a guide.

Comment: are you using connection pooling?

Comment: What do you mean by "writing packages"? Are You executing any DDL statements?

Comment: Grzegorz, "writing packages" are oracle packages (procedures).

Comment: tbone , i am not using connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

You'd either need to use the same connection without closing it or you'll need to execute both statements together as a batch:
http://www.brothersincode.com/post/executing-SQL-Plus-Batches-from-Net.aspx